# Sigmoid with Large Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sigmoid

From what I understand you use a sigmoid function to reduce a number to the range of 0-1.

Using the function found in this [library](https://github.com/stevenmiller888/sigmoid/blob/master/lib/index.js)

```
function sigmoid(z) {
  return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-z));
}
```

This works for a numbers 1-36. Any number higher than this will just return 1.

```
sigmoid(36) -> 0.9999999999999998
sigmoid(37) -> 1
sigmoid(38) -> 1
sigmoid(9000) -> 1
```

How do you increase the range so this function can handle a number larger than 36.

Comment: First divide your value by something first to make it smaller.  Take a look at a graph of the sigmoid function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is any function which has certain properties which give it the characteristic s-shape. Your question has many answers. For example, any function whose definition looks like

```
const k = 2;
function sigmoid(z) {
  return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-z/k));
}
```

will fit the bill. The larger the `k`, the larger the useful domain.

Answer (score 4):

A [Sigmoid Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) doesn't have bounds, that means it accept from infinitely small to infinitely large values.
Javascript, on the other hand, will round numbers ([IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

Anyway, what you can do is reescale your input before passing it to the formula.
Another option is tinker with the formula values, most notably the `z` value.